# Angular2 router (rc3)

Tags: typescript, angular2, router

Проблема нового роутера: если страница таже (например, auction) и мы переходим на нее - то он на нее не перейдет (даже если параметры остальные поменялись).

Если есть страница например auction/:auction_id
И мы переходим на нее так:

```
this.router.navigate(['/auction', { auction_id: id });
```

То первый раз мы успешно перейдем на нужную страницу. А затем мы пытаемся перейти на другую страницу (id другой) но страница остается старая и ничего не грузится.
По логам видно:

```
navigationStart, url=/auction;auction_id=470
navigationRecognized, url=/auction;auction_id=470
navigationEnd, url=/auction;auction_id=470
```

(первый раз auction_id был, например, 400). И хоть события navagationStart-Recognized-End происходят, страница новая не грузится.
Что надо сделать чтоб в любом случае страница грузилась? Я понимаю что как была страница /auction так она и осталась. Однако параметр же изменился

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается в новых версиях Angular при переходе на тот же компонент с другими параметрами OnInit не вызывается (вызывается только constructor). Поэтому для изменения состояния страницы надо просто менять необходимые данные в конструкторе компонента.